# C# - Same Calculation Slower Using Int vs Long?

Tags: c#, .net

I've run into something really strange while working my way through some practice problems using [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/). I have a program that applies a mathematical sequence (different calculations each step depending on whether the current step is even or odd):

```
using System;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        int ceiling = 1000000;

        int maxMoves = 0;
        int maxStart = 0;
        int testNumber;

        for(int i = 1; i <= ceiling; i++){
            testNumber = i;
            int moves = 1;
            while(testNumber != 1){
                if(testNumber % 2 == 0){
                    testNumber = testNumber / 2;
                    moves++;
                } else {
                    testNumber = (3 * testNumber) + 1;
                    moves++;
                }
            }
            if(moves > maxMoves){
                maxMoves = moves;
                maxStart = i;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(maxStart);
        Console.WriteLine(maxMoves);
    }

}
```

As written, the execution time limit gets exceeded. However, if I change the declaration of test number to a long instead of an int, the program runs:

```
int maxMoves = 0;
int maxStart = 0;
**long** testNumber;
```

Why would making this change, which requires recasting `i` from an `int` to a `long` each increment of the for loop (at `testNumber = i`), be faster than leaving this as an `int`? Is performing the mathematical operations faster on a `long` value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason seems to be an *overflow*. If you run that code enclosed in a

```
checked
{
    // your code
}
```

you get an `OverflowException` when running with `testNumber` as `int`.

The reason is that eventually `3*testNumber+1` exceeds the boundary of an `int`. In an `unchecked` context this does not throw an exception, but leads to *negative* values for `testNumber`.

At this point your sequence (I think it's [Collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), right?) does not work anymore and the calculation takes (probably infinitly) longer, because you never reach `1` (or at least it takes you a whole lot more iterations to reach `1`).

Comment: Thank you very much! And yes, that's Collatz.